# Getting unknown errors in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table Member_ID(
Member_ID not null,
Title varchar(4) not null,
Forename varchar(30) not null,
Surname varchar(30) not null,
DOB date not null,
Address 1 varchar (30), not null,
Address 2 varchar (30), not null,
Postcode varchar(8), not null,
MobileNo char (11), not null,
Email varchar (30), not null,
Gender char (1), not null,
Medical varchar (30), not null,
Joining_Date date not null,
Paid varchar (4), not null,
Membership_Type char(1), not null,
Staff_Initials char (2), not null,



Primary key (Member_ID) );

create table class(
Class_Name varchar (30) not null, 
ClassDayofWeek date not null,
Class_Time select get date not null,
Class_Duration char(4) not null,
Studio_ID char (4) not null,
Instructor_ID int not null,


create table class_list(
Class_ID varchar (30) not null,
Member_ID not null,
Date_Booked date not null,

create table Instructor(
Instructor_ID not null,
InsFirstName varchar (30) not null,
InsSurname varchar (30) not null,
InsContactNo char (11) not null,

create table Equipment(
Equip_ID not null,
Supplier_ID not null,
Studio_ID not null,
Equip_Name varchar (30),

create table supplier(
Supplier_ID not null,
Supplier_Name varchar (30) not null,
SupplierContactNo char (11) not null,
Supplier_Email varchar (30) not null,

create table Equipment_Maintanence(
Maintenence_ID not null,
EquipID not null,
Main_date date not null
Maint_ID not null,
Eng_Name varchar (30)
Fault_Desc varchar (200)
Maint_Type varchar (7)
```

Hi,
I am attempting to create a table in MySQL and am a beginner so please be patient. I am getting syntax error on lines 2, 7, 26, 32. Everything else seems to be error free and unsure. I've spent quite some time figuring out. Any advice thanks.

Comment: `);` is missing for all create table statement apart from first and remove the comma after last column

Comment: Member_ID doesn't have a type

Comment: A table called 'member_id'? That is very weird!

Comment: Better.. study database before working it..!

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add the datatype for alot of columns like `Member_ID not null` it should be `Member_ID int not null`

also if the column name have space you should be like that

```
`Address 1` varchar(30) not null
```

not

```
Address 1 varchar(30) not null
```

also `Postcode varchar(8), not null,` here there are extra `,` it should be `Postcode varchar(8) not null,`

and there few `,` and `);` you forget to write

**this seem work to me**

```
create table Member_ID(
  Member_ID int not null,
  Title varchar(4) not null,
  Forename varchar(30) not null,
  Surname varchar(30) not null,
  DOB date not null,
  `Address 1` varchar(30) not null,
  `Address 2` varchar(30) not null,
  Postcode varchar(8) not null,
  MobileNo char (11) not null,
  Email varchar (30) not null,
  Gender char (1) not null,
  Medical varchar (30) not null,
  Joining_Date date not null,
  Paid varchar(4) not null,
  Membership_Type char(1) not null,
  Staff_Initials char (2) not null,
  Primary key (Member_ID) 
);

create table class(
  Class_Name varchar (30) not null, 
  ClassDayofWeek date not null,
  `Class_Time select get` date not null,
  Class_Duration char(4) not null,
  Studio_ID char (4) not null,
  Instructor_ID int not null
);


create table class_list(
  Class_ID varchar(30) not null,
  Member_ID int not null,
  Date_Booked date not null
);

create table Instructor(
  Instructor_ID int not null,
  InsFirstName varchar (30) not null,
  InsSurname varchar (30) not null,
  InsContactNo char (11) not null
);

create table Equipment(
  Equip_ID int not null,
  Supplier_ID int not null,
  Studio_ID int not null,
  Equip_Name varchar (30)
);

create table supplier(
  Supplier_ID int not null,
  Supplier_Name varchar (30) not null,
  SupplierContactNo char (11) not null,
  Supplier_Email varchar (30) not null
);

create table Equipment_Maintanence(
  Maintenence_ID int not null,
  EquipID int not null,
  Main_date date not null,
  Maint_ID int not null,
  Eng_Name varchar(30),
  Fault_Desc varchar (200),
  Maint_Type varchar (7)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of errors in this sql, for example let's get first table "create table Member_ID(" and its

- 2nd string:
- - Member_ID not null - you should add type, for example
    int
- - Member_ID int not null - normal definition for field
- 7th string
- - Address 1 varchar (30), not null, - you should use another column name, f.e Address 1 and remove extra comma after varchar (30) and before not null
- - Address_1 varchar(30) not null  - normal definition for field

So I have fixed whole first table and get this code:

```
create table Member_ID(
    Member_ID int not null,
    Title varchar(4) not null,
    Forename varchar (30) not null,
    Surname varchar (30) not null,
    DOB date not null,
    Address_1 varchar(30) not null,
    Address_2 varchar(30) not null,
    Postcode varchar(8) not null,
    MobileNo char(11) not null,
    Email varchar(30) not null,
    Gender char(1) not null,
    Medical varchar(30) not null,
    Joining_Date date not null,
    Paid varchar(4) not null,
    Membership_Type char(1) not null,
    Staff_Initials char(2) not null,
    Primary key (Member_ID)
);
```